# How to carry out image loading in a separate thread for smooth scrolling of list view?

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how I can load images in separate threads for Smooth Scrolling.I have only been able to custom my list and the code for what I have done is given below and all that I get is a list with the images of the Avengers which happens to be behaving like a turtle when scrolled.Anyone providing suggestions from previous questions are equally welcome as the one's helping out with answers

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String []titles = {"CAPTAIN AMERICA", "DOCTOR STRANGE", "THOR", "SPIDERMAN"};
String []desciption = {"CHRIS EVANS", "BENEDICT CUMBERBATCH", "CHRIS HEMSWORTH", "TOM HOLLAND"};
int []image = {R.drawable.capamerica, R.drawable.doctorstrange, R.drawable.thor, R.drawable.spidey};
ListView lv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    MyAdapter adap = new MyAdapter(this, titles, desciption, image);
    lv.setAdapter(adap);
}
```

}

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
String []title;
String []desc;
Context context;
int []img;;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] titles, String[] desciption, int[] image)
{
    context = mainActivity;
    title = titles;
    desc = desciption;
    img = image;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return title.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView title;
    private TextView description;
    private ImageView image;
}

ViewHolder holder;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titlestring);
        holder.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionstring);
        holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgview);
        view.setTag(holder);

    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }


    holder.title.setText(title[position]);
    holder.description.setText(desc[position]);
    holder.image.setImageResource(img[position]);
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: You can use Glide or picasso library for loading them. they will load image from a different thread and also have caching in them. 
https://github.com/bumptech/glide 
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @karandeepsingh quick question.How does what you just said differ from what I intended to do??

Comment: The libraries I mentioned load images in different thread and takes care ov boilerplate code you may need to write to take care for various stuff

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using something like Glide or Picasso.

If those are not options however, you can use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Since you are using them in a recycler view, you will need to make sure that you can cancel any image requests that have not completed when a view is recycled.

Comment: I'd love to try out what you just said provided I knew how to.You see I've been coding in Android for only a couple of months now and I believe you can understand that I'm pretty much of an amateur.If it's convenient for you,do you think you can like maybe write the code or do something of that sort??

Comment: The link that I provided to the Android developer documentation explains how to use AsyncTasks pretty thoroughly. The documentation for Glide can be found here: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/

Answer (score 0):

Would be best if you use Glide of Picasso. With 2-3 lines of code you will get everything in a new thread. Super easy.

Here is a tutorial: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en